# What is formatunicorn for strings?

Tags: discussion, javascript, unicorns

This is a serious post about unicorns!

Here is a unicorn for everyone's enjoyment

[image]

But in all seriousness, I was testing out some stuff for a Javascript question on strings, so I opened up the Javascript console in Chrome, and I typed in `new String()`, and I saw what properties/methods it had. One of these methods was `formatunicorn()`, with the code

```
function (){var d=this.toString();if(!arguments.length)return d;var a=typeof arguments[0],a="string"==a||"number"==a?Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments):arguments[0],c;for(c in a)d=d.replace(RegExp("\\{"+c+"\\}","gi"),a[c]);return d}
```

What is this for? I'm assuming it has something to do with a unicornify April Fool's joke. Also, since this question is about programming somewhat, is it more on-topic in SO?

Comment: Should I ask this on SO? I wasn't sure, since it pertains to SO, but also code.

Comment: It just replaces `{token}`s in strings, for injecting parameters into routes for AJAX requests, etc.

Comment: Is this something that's actually in the Stack Exchange JavaScript? It's not immediately clear. I'm trying to figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: @animuson just go to the js console, and type in `"my string".formatunicorn`.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, it's a SE utility function.

Comment: Cool. I just found the name interesting.

Comment: Usage of `String#formatUnicorn()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format/18234317#18234317

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`formatUnicorn` is just a utility function for subbing in values to simple string templates in various places in the Stack Exchange JavaScript, using curly braces as the token delimiter. It's used on things like request routes to inject parameters.

As for the name, we can only guess…

[image: Unicorn, sort of...]<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*It knows it's an abomination, don't stare at it!</sup>

Comment: Too late, can't unsee it now.

Comment: It's beautiful!